# Django UserCreationForm neither gives error message nor registering user

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-forms

I am beginner to python Django. And trying build an posting article website with the help of tutorials. I got stuck at UserCreationForm. I have created a form using UserCreationForm, but when I am submitting the form I am not able to neither submit the form nor getting any error message on the page.

My **views.py** code

```
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 from django.contrib import auth
 from django.template.context_processors import csrf
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

 def register_user(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    print args
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)


 def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

**register.html**

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

 {% block content %}

    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

      {{form}}

      <input type="submit" value="Register"/>

   </form>

  {% endblock %}
```

**register_success.html**

```
  {% extends "base.hml" %}

  {% block content %}

   <h2>You have registered!</h2>
   <p>Click <a href="/accounts/login/">Here</a> to login again</p>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your HTML to see if <form> method is POST? What about adding `else return HttpResponse('Not from POST method')` on **register_user**

Comment: is not `{{ args.form }}` ?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. It gives me"Not from post"

Comment: @NeerajSharma I've updated my answer

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I am receive the following error                          "The view django_demo.views.register_user didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are always creating a blank form.

```
args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
```

This means that you do not see any errors for POST requests when the form is invalid.

Instead, you should only create the blank form for GET requests.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', args)
```

Note that I have simplified the view by using `render` instead of the obsolete `render_to_response`. That means you don't need to handle csrf manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/), specifically CreateView, it will make your life a lot easier. You can use it like so:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CreateUserView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/accounts/register_success'
```

Add this to your `urls.py` and you are good to go:

```
from mysite.views import CreateUserView

# add this url pattern
url(r'^sign_up/$', CreateUserView.as_view(), name='signup'),
```